# Difference between Crosses & Intersects - Shapely (Python)

Tags: python, geojson, shapely, intersect

I have two questions :

I have some lines (eg: road network). I want to find coordinates of each junction.

1. Should i use *crosses* or *intersects* function from python's Shapely module? They are giving different counts.
2. Moreover these functions return boolean value. How to get the junction coordinates ?

   ```
   with open('./lines.geojson') as f:
       lines = json.load(f)

   line = []

   for feature in lines['features']:
       line.append(feature['geometry']['coordinates'])

   count = 0
   for i in range(len(line)-1): 
      j =i+1 
      while (j < len(line)):        
           l1 = LineString(line[i])
           l2 = LineString(line[j])
           if l1.crosses(l2)== True :
               count =count+1        
           j = j+1
   ```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. From [Shapely's doc](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html):

> [`intersects()`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#object.intersects) is equivalent to the OR-ing of `contains()`, `crosses()`, `equals()`, `touches()`, and `within()`.

So there might be some cases where two lines intersect eachother without crossing, in particular when one line contains another or when two lines are equals.

More specifically:

> `crosses()` returns `True` [...] if the dimension of the intersection
> is less than the dimension of the one or the other.

So if two lines overlap, they won't be considered as "crossing".

2. [`intersection()`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#object.intersection) will return a geometric object.

Comment: Thanks! just wanted to add that coordinates of the junction points can be extract using object.coords[0] .